# uitable with cell array that contains array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array, matlab-uitable

I'm trying to build a GUI to edit `.mat` files. I now want to edit a `.mat` file that contains a cell array of which some cells contain double arrays (like `[20 30]`). I load the `.mat` file in a `uitable`, but now I get the error:

> Data within a cell array must have size [1 1]

I think this is because there are double arrays in the cell array. I use the GUIfor other `.mat` files and there it works just fine.
I'm now trying to figure out how to solve this. Maybe I could convert the double arrays to strings and convert back to double after editing?
Hopefully there is a better solution.

Edit:
Okay, here is some code if that helps:

```
load("file.mat"); %loads matfile from file.mat
oldTable = uitable('Parent', layout, 'Data', "matfile");
```

Comment: You need to provide a littlebit more information, paste some code or anything helpful to understand the question better.